# Inconsistency in retrieving values from android sqlite database

Tags: android, sql, database, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my android application, I have a sqlite database stored under \assets\database\myApp.sqlite

On application loading, I will check whether myApp.sqlite file (database) is available in phone and if its not available, I will store it in a particular location.

**My Application:**

I will retrieve user's current location and pass these coordinate to the below mentioned query. This query will search for the nearest location from user's current point in myApp.sqlite (my local database) and retrieve the nearest single location.

**Query to find the nearest location from particular point:**

```
SELECT *, MIN( (latitude - USER LATITUDE) * (latitude - USER LATITUDE) + (USER LONGITUDE- longitude)*(USER LONGITUDE- longitude) ) AS DISTANCE FROM my_nearest_location_table ORDER BY DISTANCE
```

**My Issue is:**

The above query works properly only in some devices. However, when I tried to execute my application (the same query) in some other devices like HTC ONE V, some other wrong values (location) is retrieved.  I am not sure whether something wrong with the above query call or reading records from my local database.

For testing, I also loaded this local database and tested the above same query in SQLite Manager (FireFox plugin). Nearest location values are retrieved properly. Only in some particular device like HTC One V, Samsung Duos wrong values are retrieved.

**My code is as follows:**

```
    public final String DATABASE_NAME="myApp.sqlite";           
    database = new MySQLiteHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1).getWritableDatabase();
    BASE_URL = "data/data/com.myApp.xxxx/databases/"+DATABASE_NAME; 

    //To get nearest area from user's location
    public List<Location> getRecordsByLatAndLong(Context theContext, double theLat, double theLng)
    {
            String aSelectQuery;
            List<Location> aLocationList = new ArrayList<Location>();

            aSelectQuery = "SELECT *, MIN((latitude - "+theLat+") * (latitude - "+theLat+")" +
                    " + ("+theLng+"- longitude)*("+theLng+"- longitude)) AS DISTANCE " +
                    "FROM train_stations ORDER BY DISTANCE";

            Cursor aCursor = database.rawQuery(aSelectQuery, null);
            try
            {
                if (aCursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do {
                        Location aLocation = new Location();
                        aLocation.setLocationId(aCursor.getInt(0));
                        aLocation.setLocationName(aCursor.getString(1));
                        aLocation.setLocationCode(aCursor.getString(2));
                        aLocation.setLat(aCursor.getDouble(3));
                        aLocation.setLng(aCursor.getDouble(4));
                        aLocationList.add(aLocation);
                    } while(aCursor.moveToNext());
                }
                aCursor.close();
            }
            catch (Exception theException) {
                System.out.println("Exception..."+ theException);
            }
            return aLocationList;
    }
```

Can anyone please guide me why there is such inconsistency in retrieving results from a particular database (for a same query).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Hm, did you actually extract the minimum **DISTANCE** value from the Cursor?

Example

```
    ...
    aLocation.setDistance(aCursor.getDouble(5));
```

Comment: No.. Actually I don't have DISTANCE value in my local database. Through the above query, we will calculate the distance and get the first value (distance which is closer to user location)..

Comment: because your query does have a MIN aggregate function as DISTANCE? I'm not sure if that helps your problem, but if that is not intended, consider removing it. The ORDER BY also serves no purpose for single row results.

Comment: sorry if I am wrong. I am already having a MIN(distance_calculation_formulae) as DISTANCE.. Then using the ORDER BY for the received DISTANCE value

Comment: ok I understand now. what you need is an SQL like

"SELECT * FROM train_station WHERE distance = MIN(distance)"